# Listing the resolved properties in Spring

Tags: java, spring

I have multiple property file sources in my spring xml files, they have different order values and some are optional.

- application.properties - in the classpath, holds the default (fallback) properties (lowest priority)
- [HOSTNAME].properties - in the classpath, holds properties specific for that hostname (higher priority)
- Property file loaded by value in jndi - location specified in via jndi, highest priority.

In other words, I can override the default properties set in application.properties with properties in .properties and override those values in turn by a property file whose location is looked up by jndi.

What I would like to have however is some way for spring to give my a list of the resolved values of all the properties. Anyone know how I can do this?

It's easy for me to get the value of a particular property but what I actually need is a list of all the resolved properties.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring: access all Environment properties as a Map or Properties object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23506471/spring-access-all-environment-properties-as-a-map-or-properties-object)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have two suggestions:

1. You can override the class `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` with method `processProperties` to populate all the resolved properties. An example is listed [here](http://j2eecookbook.blogspot.com/2007/07/accessing-properties-loaded-via-spring.html).
2. Since `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` implements Spring's `Ordered` interface, you can have multiple property place holders; then, assign them the `order` in the order that should be in your application. Finally, having been already extended the class, you will have access to all resolved properties in the order that should be loaded.