# Spring MVC @PropertySource all Key/value as a map

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, dictionary, properties

In my Spring MVC application, I want to read **ALL key/values** from a specify properties file.
I am including the properties file to my java class by

```
@PropertySource("classpath:user-form-validation-configuration.properties")
```

and can read a one key at a time

```
@Autowired
Environment env;
```

and `env.getProperty("userIdEmail")`

Please help me how to get all key/value as a **map**

Thanks
Manu

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to achieve the same is [Spring: access all Environment properties as a Map or Properties object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23506471/spring-access-all-environment-properties-as-a-map-or-properties-object) and secondly is:

```
<bean id="myProperties" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean">
  <property name="location" value="classpath:user-form-validation-configuration.properties"/>
</bean>
```

For, Annotation based:

```
@Bean(name = "myProperties")
public static PropertiesFactoryBean mapper() {
        PropertiesFactoryBean bean = new PropertiesFactoryBean();
        bean.setLocation(new ClassPathResource(
                "user-form-validation-configuration.properties"));
        return bean;
}
```

Then you can pick them up in your application with:

```
@Resource(name = "myProperties")
private Map<String, String> myProperties;
```

Comment: Thanks lot Arpit,Second option is more clean and clear.But can I avoid the bean creation in xml file.direct can include the properties file in my  Java class, or annotated class to load the properties file.

Comment: yes got it, in jjava I am able to configure .@Bean(name="myProperties")
    public static PropertiesFactoryBean mapper() {
        PropertiesFactoryBean bean = new PropertiesFactoryBean();
        bean.setLocation(new ClassPathResource("user-form-validation-configuration.properties"));
        return bean;
    }

Comment: Updated the post, for annotation based.

Comment: @Manu: accept the answer, if it works - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: @Manu you should accept useful answers, that's the way this site works