# How to get raw value of property containing placeholders?

Tags: java, spring, spring-el

I am trying to define the following property in one of my .properties files:

```
personExpression=${person.surname}
```

This is then read by a config class:

```
@Configuration
public class TemplateConfig {
    @Autowired
    private Environment environment;

    public String getPersonExpression() {
        return environment.getProperty("personExpression");
    }
}
```

However this gives the exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'person.surname' in string value "${person.surname}"
```

Is there a way to do get `getPersonExpression()` to return the string literal `${person.surname}` without attempting to resolve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get this to work takes some pretty unintuitive syntax.

You essentially have to split your expression into two parts and wrap the whole thing in a parent SpEL expression to join them.

If you change your property value to the following it should work:

```
personExpression=#{'$' + '{person.surname}'}
```

This works because you're splitting up the `$` character from the `{person.surname}` so SpEL won't try to evaluate it as an expression, because as far as it's concerned, you're just concatenating two strings together.

Comment: Is there some additional configuration that needs to be added to get spring to evaluade expressions inside #{..}?
I tried changing the property to `#{'$' + '{person.surname}'}` but `getPersonExpression()` just returns `#{'$' + '{person.surname}'}`

Comment: Are you using a `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` bean? That should read your properties file, parse the values, and then make them available. If you aren't, then the properties file won't be parsed using SpEL.

Comment: Yep this was the issue. I had no `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` bean registered as there were no other properties that were being evaluated. Adding in  `@Bean
 public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer() {
  return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
 }` did the trick. Also I messed around with the formatting a bit and changed the property to `personExpression=#{'$'}{person.surname}` which still works and is a bit easier to read

Comment: Additionally it looks like it only works if the property is retrieved using `@Value("${personExpression}")`. `environment.getProperty("personExpression")` just returns `#{'$'}{person.surname}` without evaluating it

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any `getRawPropertyValue` type method that's accessible through the `ApplicationContext`.

If you know the name of your `PropertySource`, eg. `example`, you can get the `ConfigurableEnvironment`, and its registered `PropertySource`s, retrieve the appropriate one, and get the required property value.

```
AnnotationConfigApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(Sample.class);
ConfigurableEnvironment configurableEnvironment = ctx.getEnvironment();
String rawValue = configurableEnvironment.getPropertySources()
                       .get("example") // get property source
                       .getProperty("personExpression"); // get property
```

The variable `rawValue` will have the value `${person.surname}`. All this is done outside any property placeholder resolvers.

This will obviously only work for property sources registered with the `Environment`.

Comment: In my case, I was able to `@Autowire` in a `ConfigurableEnvironment` and skip retrieving the context.  Everything is the same.

Answer (score -1):

you might know this, but i'm just clarifying ${} is used to retrieve a property from properties file in to an XML file/ any other file where valid.

If you are trying to set personExpression= "person.surname" and want to retrieve it as you are doing it above (environment.getProperty("personExpression");) you should define like this **personExpression= person.surname** in your properties file. then it will work with **environment.getProperty("personExpression")**; and returns **person.surname** in your function, hope this helps