# How print all spring properties including dependencies?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, properties

Here is a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23506471/spring-access-all-environment-properties-as-a-map-or-properties-object) which offer a [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23536981/1251549) to print all properties. But in fact it prints all properties from `.properties` files in **application sources**, system and environment properties. But it ignore all properties from

- `additional-spring-configuration-metadata.json`
- `spring-configuration-metadata.json`
- `spring-autoconfigure-metadata.properties`
- and others from `json` or `properties` in project dependencies
- any properties which is considered as present in `org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.ConditionalOnProperty` annotation, with *matchIfMissing* key word, like that `@ConditionalOnProperty(prefix = "spring.data.solr.repositories", name = "enabled", havingValue = "true", matchIfMissing = true)`

Even I can not find any variable inside `Environment env` which points to any of these properties.

So is there a way to print all properties both from current application sources and from imported dependencies/jars, especially which are generated via by annotations?

Comment: Those `metadata` files don't contain properties those are only for the IDE to provide information on the well known properties. The `@Conditional` rule you point out also doesn't add anything as a property which should be clear by `matchIfMissing` if it isn't available the rule matches, but this doesn't mean the property is available.

Comment: "Those metadata files don't contain properties" but they define default values for some properties, so this value is used somewhere I think.

Comment: No they don't. It is only metadata for use in IDE's . The defaults are in the `@ConfigurationProperties` annotated classes. They are in those metadata files for reference.

Comment: Do you mean that metadata files are generated from `@ConfigurationProperties` annotations? Could you please provied a proof link to that?

Comment: Not sure how the spring team generates those (or if they are generated at all). But it is a fact that those aren't into play for defining properties as stated those are only for the IDE.