# External Configuration

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have large project that downloads its configuration from an external source. and the refers to them with @value annotation with their specified name. My question can I some how print all these external configurations is it possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you inject [org.springframework.core.env.Environment](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/env/Environment.html) you can get all the defined configuration properties.
Check out [Spring: access all Environment properties as a Map or Properties object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23506471/spring-access-all-environment-properties-as-a-map-or-properties-object) for additional info.

Comment: I have done that but still there are some @value parameters whose key are not present in that map but they are getting values which are not defined any where in the project. I am pretty new to spring so pardon me if am wrong about the terminology.