# How to convert @Propertysource file to Map?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have my contents in .properties file. I'm loading the properties file using @PropertySource.

How do i get the contents from the properties file to map using @PropertySource Annotation?

My Property file looks like this:

```
a= abc
b= bcd
c= cde
```

In my Component, I want to read the property file and put the contents in a map.

```
@PropertySource("classpath:myData.properties")
public class myComponentService {

@Autowired
private Environment environment;

Map<String, String> myMap = new HashMap<String, String>(); //Property file content goes here

}
```

I tried something like this, but this doesn't work.

```
Map<String, String> myMap= new HashMap<String, String>();
Properties myProperties = new Properties();
myProperties .putAll(myMap);
```

Comment: please refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23506471/spring-access-all-environment-properties-as-a-map-or-properties-object)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring: access all Environment properties as a Map or Properties object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23506471/spring-access-all-environment-properties-as-a-map-or-properties-object)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so, I tried with the following two methods, they both worked:

Method 1: content of my properties file looks like this-

```
search.myprop.a = abc
search.myprop.b = bcd
search.myprop.c = def
```

In my java component:

```
import org.springframework.core.env.AbstractEnvironment;
import org.springframework.core.env.ConfigurableEnvironment;
import org.springframework.core.env.EnumerablePropertySource;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.core.env.MapPropertySource;
import org.springframework.core.env.PropertySource;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
....
@org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource("classpath:myproperty-file-.properties")
public class MyBaseClass {
    @Autowired
    private Environment environment;
...
Map<String, String> myMap= new HashMap<String, String>();
    for (PropertySource<?> propertySource : ((ConfigurableEnvironment) environment).getPropertySources()) {
                            if (propertySource instanceof EnumerablePropertySource) {
                                for (String key : ((EnumerablePropertySource) propertySource).getPropertyNames()) {
                                    if (key.startsWith("search")) {
                                        myMap.put(key.replace("search.myprop.", ""), propertySource.getProperty(key).toString());
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
```

This worked perfectly as I wanted. But unnecessarily iterating through all the properties' file is the downside. The better way is using @ConfigurationProperties annotation.
Reference: [https://www.baeldung.com/configuration-properties-in-spring-boot][1]

Method 2:

1. create a configuration file.

   ```
   import java.util.Map;
   import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
   import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
   import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;

   @Configuration
   @PropertySource("classpath:myproperty-file.properties")
   @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "search")
   public class MypropConfigProperties {
    private Map<String, String> myprop;

    public Map<String, String> getMyProp() {
       return myprop;
   }

   public void setMyProp(Map<String, String> myprop) {
           this.myprop= myprop;
       }
   }
   ```
2. In your java class

   ```
   public class MyBaseClass {
   private MypropConfigProperties mypropConfigProperties;

   @Autowired
   public void setMyProp(MypropConfigProperties mypropConfigProperties) {
   this.mypropConfigProperties= mypropConfigProperties;
   }
   .....
   log.info(this.mypropConfigProperties.getMyProp().toString()); // this does the final magic
   ....
   ```

Answer (score 3):

There is a better (**cleaner**) way to do that by creating a Configuration Property bean as follow :

```
@Data
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "custom")
public class CustomPropertiesConfig {

    private Map<String, String> connection= new HashMap<>();

}
```

And then define your map in application.yml ( Yaml property file ) like this :

```
custom:
  connection:
    key1: value1
    key2: value2
```

And last but not least :

```
@Log4j2
@EnableConfigurationProperties
@SpringBootApplication
public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(App.class);
    }

    @Bean
    CommandLineRunner run(CustomPropertiesConfig config){
       return (args)->{
           Map<String, String> connection = config.getConnection();
           if(connection.containsKey("key1")){
               log.info("holla");
           }
       };
    }

}
```

Note that :

> Spring Framework provides two convenient classes that can be used to
>   load YAML documents. The YamlPropertiesFactoryBean loads YAML as
>   Properties and the YamlMapFactoryBean loads YAML as a Map.

And that :

> YAML files cannot be loaded by using the @PropertySource annotation.
>   So, in the case that you need to load values that way, you need to use
>   a properties file.

So this answer is valid when you are trying to bind to a map from a yaml properties file

Comment: yup, this @ConfigurationProperties is a lot better and cleaner way.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, not sure, what you want to do...

Usually @PropertySource is used like this:

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:config.properties")
public class DbConfig {

@Value("${db.url}")
private String dbUrl;

@Value("${db.user}")
private String dbUser;

...
```

with "db.url" and "db.user" being specified in "config.properties".

Maybe you should look into the Environment class of Spring, too:

```
@Autowired
private Environment environment;
```

Answer (score 0):

Provide this is Spring XML Configuration

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath*:database.properties,classpath*:query.properties"/>
```

there by you can use  below annotation in application.

```
@Value("${propertiesName}")
```