# How to retrieve the field names from Spring Value annotations?

Tags: java, spring

In my class I have:

```
@Component
public class AwgTekConsumerProperties {

    @Value("${awgtek_topic_consumer.default_thread_pool_size:10}")
    private Integer defaultThreadPoolSize;

    @Value("${awgtek_topic_consumer.default_keep_alive_time:10}")
    private Integer defaultKeepAliveTime;

    ....
}
```

I would like to retrieve a list of the field values, i.e. `["awgtek_topic_consumer.default_thread_pool_size", "awgtek_topic_consumer.default_keep_alive_time",...]`

What I have tried is: `Set<String> consumperPropertyNames = FieldUtils
                .getFieldsListWithAnnotation(AwgTekConsumerProperties.class, Value.class).stream()
                .map(field -> ((Value) Arrays.stream(field.getDeclaredAnnotations()).filter(a -> a instanceof Value).findFirst().get()).value())
                .collect(Collectors.toSet());`

But this results in the whole field name, i.e. `["${awgtek_topic_consumer.default_thread_pool_size:10}", "${awgtek_topic_consumer.default_keep_alive_time:10}"..]` including Spring EL and defaults.
Is there a way to parse out only the field name using Spring utilities or some other elegant way? I tried looking into Spring Expression Language but could not find the way to parse it out, but I probably missed something. Is there a better way than doing `String.indexOf` etc.?

Comment: Do you need property names used in that particular class or all system/environment properties loaded into Spring context?

Comment: Just the ones in that class.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23506471/spring-access-all-environment-properties-as-a-map-or-properties-object
Refer it