# Can you evaluate what a variable would be with @Value annotation in spring at runtime

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, debugging

I am having issues using my properties with @Value annotation and I am wondering is there a way when debugging to check the value of an @Value annotation. For example I would stop at a breakpoint in my code and evaluate

```
@Value("${myString}")
String x;
```

or say if i wanted to check the spring profile i would evaluate

```
@Value("${spring.profiles.active}")
String springProfile;
```

I do only see null values for these though?

Comment: how did you instantiate the class those values are in?

Comment: I am wondering is it possible to do this from the evaluator in my IDE, say if I hadn't created String x in any class but wish to see if i could read the property that way from the debugger

Comment: intellij shows values of @Value even in compile time - just use intellij and you will see the values that will be set

Comment: Yea I use intellij, but I mean if i use the evaluator from intellij and I haven't set the @value in the code anywhere can i check what it would be if i had of

Comment: Are you using @Value in a Spring bean?

Comment: To programmatically check (list) what properties Spring Boot knows, see this question: [Spring: access all Environment properties as a Map or Properties object](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23506471/5221149). --- However, it is equally likely that you're using the annotation wrong, i.e. that the class in question is not a Spring Bean, but with the code taken out of context, as it currently is, we can't say if that is the case.

Comment: So I was wondering is there a way to check if we were not using anything in a spring bean but rather stopped at a breakpoint and then trying to evaluate but i think @Andreas that will answer my question if I can list all properties. Put it as an answer if you wish and i will accept

Comment: @AnonymousAlias if you apply the annotation correctly, sure, you can, because the value will be assigned before you can call the code.

Comment: @AnonymousAlias To answer your first question: yes you can see the value as that gets assigned while the bean is initializing. For the second one: it should be a managed bean then only these values will get initialized

Comment: @AnonymousAlias I wouldn't answer, I would close as duplicate of that other answer, except I can't do that right now. Maybe someone else will.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The spring values will be initialized before we call the code so we will be able to evaluate all spring properties at run time.